# How to do a carousel with data by api using pure JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

Using a pure javascript, I have an api that bring me 30 images, That is working, all of images are in my page, butI limited to show 2 in a page or 1 with max media 768px, they are limited by the width of my div. Also I created a button that need to pass to the next or previous image, that is my problem, I need some function in javascript that will to next or previous

```js
const linkApi = "https://picsum.photos/v2/list";

const container = document.querySelector("#card-2-projectsList");
let contentHTML = '';

fetch(linkApi)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {

    for (const results of data) {
      contentHTML += `
      <li class="card-2-listContent">
    <img class="card-2-projectImages" src="${results.download_url}">
    </li>`
    }
    container.innerHTML = contentHTML;
  })
```

```css
.card-2-projects {
    width: 100%;
}

.card-2-projectsTitle {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.card-2-projectsCarousel {
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.card-2-projectBtn {
    width: 10px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #C4C8CC;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    clip-path: polygon(0% 50%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%);
}
.card-2-projectBtn:last-child {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.card-2-projectBtn:hover {
    background-color: #5A5789;
}



.card-2-projectsDivList {
    flex-grow: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 400px;
}

.card-2-projectsList {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    transition: left .25s ease;
 
   
}

.card-2-listContent {
    height: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    margin: 0 10px 9px;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px #2E2D2C66;
    cursor: pointer;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}



@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .card-2-listContent {
        width: calc(50% - 20px);
        padding-bottom: 30%;
    }
}

.card-2-projectImages {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 2px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 1;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.card-2-projectImages:hover {
opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-2-projects">
                    <label class="card-2-projectsTitle">Your Projects:</label>
                    <div class="card-2-projectsCarousel">
                        <button class="card-2-projectBtn" onclick="someFunction(-1)">
                        </button>
                        <div class="card-2-projectsDivList">
                            <ul class="card-2-projectsList" id="card-2-projectsList">

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <button class="card-2-projectBtn" onclick="someFunction(0)">
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

My problem is just put both button, left and right to work